# Operation not permitted when executing an arbitrary binary

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-lambda, terraform

In [Running arbitrary binary](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/), AWS explains:

> Including your own executables is easy; just package them in the ZIP file you upload, and then reference them (including the relative path within the ZIP file you created) when you call them from Node.js or from other processes that you’ve previously started. Ensure that you include the following at the start of your function code:
> process.env[‘PATH’] = process.env[‘PATH’] + ‘:’ + process.env[‘LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT’]
> You can use all the usual forms of interprocess communication as well as files in /tmp to communicate with any of the processes you create.

I would like to use the Go Terraform library `tfexec` in my code, but I consistently get Permission denied.

Code in `main/tf`:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "runtime"
    "strings"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/tfexec"
)

func Start() error {
    fmt.Printf("Go version: %s\n", runtime.Version())
    fmt.Println()

    // set environment variable, cf https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/
    newPath := []string{
        os.Getenv("PATH"),
        ":",
        os.Getenv("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"),
    }
    os.Setenv("PATH", strings.Join(newPath, ""))

    // Get path to binary
    fmt.Println("Start terraform")
    currDir, err := os.Getwd()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    tfBinary := filepath.Join(currDir, "terraform")

    stat, err := os.Stat(tfBinary)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    fmt.Printf("Stat %s: ", tfBinary)
    fmt.Println(stat.Mode())

    // Start new instance of terraform
    tf, err := tfexec.NewTerraform(currDir, tfBinary)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    tf.SetStdout(os.Stdout)
    tf.SetStderr(os.Stderr)

    // run terraform init
    fmt.Println("Tf init")
    if err = tf.Init(context.Background()); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func main() {
    // Start()
    lambda.Start(Start)
}
```

Setup:

```
curl -X GET -o terraform https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.29/terraform_0.12.29_linux_amd64.zip
chmod 755 terraform
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build create-vpc-tf.go
zip zip.zip terraform main
# Create Lambda running on go1.x with `main` as handler
```

Result:

```
START RequestId: f23e4122-3595-48ef-808f-ef7951531f59 Version: $LATEST
Go version: go1.16

Start terraform
Stat /var/task/terraform: -rwxr-xr-x
Tf init
fork/exec /var/task/terraform: operation not permitted
fork/exec /var/task/terraform: operation not permitted: PathError
null
END RequestId: f23e4122-3595-48ef-808f-ef7951531f59
REPORT RequestId: f23e4122-3595-48ef-808f-ef7951531f59  Duration: 2.26 ms   Billed Duration: 3 ms   Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 32 MB  Init Duration: 83.85 ms
```

This works as expected locally (I have not provided a `*.tf` file so terraform correctly reports  `Terraform initialized in an empty directory!`.

Comment: In a Lambda, `/var/task` is read-only. So `terraform init` would fail because it couldn't write the `.terraform` directory. But since your error message indicates a problem with fork or exec, that doesn't seem like the issue.

Comment: I see a mistake that could cause you some problems... :)

Comment: ...But I can't explain how it works for you locally, if this is really what you've run...

Comment: Hint - Add this to your script: `file terraform`

Comment: Here's what I think I see.  You've downloaded `terraform_0.12.29_linux_amd64.zip`, then attempted to execute that .zip file.  It needs to be unzipped at some point.  I don't see any indication that NewTerraform doesn't expect a raw executable: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/blob/main/tfexec/terraform.go#L64

Comment: ...So your `zip.zip` file contains a double-zipped file.  You may have observed something like this: `adding: terraform (deflated 0%)`, which indicates that your `zip` stage wan't able to compress the 'terraform' file (because it was already compressed).

Comment: Let me know if on the wrong track here (with an explanation).  I'm trying to help, but I'm also here to learn.

Comment: If your `stat` output included the file size, it would reduce a bit of ambiguity about whether or not the decompression has somehow been performed.  You could also do the `file terraform` during setup as I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @BrentBradburn I might have skipped this but I am downloading the binary. However if I did that mistake and tried to execute a binary, the error would be `exec format error: ./terraform`, not `operation not permitted: PathError`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue relates to the `tfexec` library and its operability within an AWS lambda / Firecracker environment. It is not allowed to fork a process in a Firecracker environment.

`Pdeathsig` forces a fork, therefore it can't be used in AWS lambda.

Terraform itself doesn't use it, but `tfexec` does, [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/blob/main/tfexec/cmd_linux.go#L18).

A quick Google shows that other projects ran into the same issue, example [here](https://github.com/vansante/go-ffprobe/issues/23).

We packaged the fix shown [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/issues/172) in order to prevent `Pdeathsig` from being set. This is making a change to the `tfexec` library directly, which hopefully they will absorb upstream. Meanwhile, we packaged `tfexec` in our `vendor` directory directly with `go mod` and we made the change there directly. Works nicely.

```
go mod init [repo]
go mod download
go mod vendor
```

Update  `vendor/github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/tfexec/cmd_linux.go` as follows:

```
if _, ok := os.LookupEnv("LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT"); !ok {
    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        // kill children if parent is dead
        Pdeathsig: syscall.SIGKILL,
        // set process group ID
        Setpgid: true,
    }
}
```

Rebuild your project: `go1.16 build main.go`.

Re-package and upload to your lambda.

Answer (score 0):

You've downloaded the Terraform binary as a zip file, so it isn't in a form that can be executed.

You'll need to decompress it before repackaging it with `zip`.

Replace:

```
curl -X GET -o terraform https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.29/terraform_0.12.29_linux_amd64.zip
```

With:

```
curl https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/0.12.29/terraform_0.12.29_linux_amd64.zip |zcat >terraform
```

---

When you run this locally, you should see something like:

> Your version of Terraform is out of date!

Since [the version](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases/tag/v0.12.29) used in the question is ... out of date.

If you aren't seeing a message to that effect, it's a strong clue that your local test isn't actually using the file you downloaded in the setup shown.

---

### A safer way to download the Terraform binary

Alternatively, you can use `tfinstall` to download and implicitly decompress the latest version at runtime, as shown in [this example](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec#terraform-exec).

```
execPath, err := tfinstall.Find(context.Background(), tfinstall.LatestVersion(tmpDir, false))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("error locating Terraform binary: %s", err)
}
```

This approach uses Hashicorp's custom downloader [go-getter](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter), which simultaneously [verifies the checksum](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter#checksumming) and performs [streaming decompression](https://github.com/hashicorp/go-getter#unarchiving).  *`tfinstall` even uses Hashicorp's public key to [verify](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-exec/blob/d944f539075d1a44009fdb7c3342a8ce1bf37b2f/tfinstall/download.go#L100) that the checksum file itself hasn't been tampered with.*

If you want to avoid downloading terraform every time you run, you could just use `tfinstall` locally, and capture the result for reuse (essentially just replacing the `curl` in your setup).

Comment: It's good practice to also verify the checksums after downloading, as mentioned here: https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html, but you would need to do that before decompressing.

Comment: Trying to follow through with the `gpg` instructions indicated [here](https://www.hashicorp.com/security) is driving me to insanity.

Comment: You can you `tfinstall` to get the binary directly and verify its checksum. I initially did this, but changed my approach because it resulted in the same issue as shown in the post. I thought there might be a `noexec` option on the `/tmp` folder which would make sense for security reasons (`/tmp` is the only writeable folder so it's the only place where it can be downloaded). I elected to refer to the AWS documentation, which recommends to package your binary directly. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-executables-in-aws-lambda/

Comment: @Pauline, Regarding `/tmp` folder: You _can_ execute from there -- I verified by running the downloaded binary with something like `exec.Command(execPath,"init").Run()`.  I also found, as your answer states, that you can break this by setting `Pdeathsig: syscall.SIGKILL` in `SysProcAttr` prior to calling `Run()`.

Comment: ...But, yeah, my answer only addresses _part_ of the problem presented in the question. :)